# Copy text to clipboard on toolbar button click

Tags: javascript, clipboard, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making a ff webextension that is a `browser_action` button on the toolbar, and when clicked it generates a password and copies it to the clipboard.
I added the `clipboardWrite` permission to the manifest, and my code is really simple:

html:

```
<body>
  <form>

      <label for"pw">your password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pw" name="pw">

      <button id="copy">copy to clipboard</button>

  </form>
  <script src="pwgen.js"></script>
</body>
```

now, when I click the `copy` button, this js is executed:

```
function copypasstoclippboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById('pw');
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

If I execute the function by pressing the button it works, but if I execute the same function on load of the html of the popup, the `document.execCommand('copy')` line gets executed, and I see no error in the console, but the text is not copied to the clipboard.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation that is imposed by Firefox for security reasons. However, there is a way to make it work. I haven't tested this code, but this is the idea (from within a background script):

```
var code = `
  window.addEventListener("paste", function(){
    var copyText = document.getElementById("pw");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  });
  document.execCommand("paste");
`
browser.tabs.executeScript({code: code});
```

You trigger an event (in this case, paste) which is allowed to copy to the clipboard. You're running the code in the content script in this case, so the execCommand methods should work. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I added the `clipboardRead`permission to the manifest, but unfortunately the `paste` event never gets executed

Comment: this works, but this way I am injecting a script in the current open page. so it only works if a) there is a page open, and b) the page is scriptable and c) the page does not cancel my copy action. since I am copying a password to the users clipboard, I'd rather don't interact with a random webpage to so that...

Comment: I understand your concerns. However, there is currently no other way I know of to achieve the same result.